# How do I dynamically change the table accessed using DynamoDB's Java Mapper?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a few DynamoDB tables, all of which have entries of the same structure. I want to create a single POJO to represent all of these entries and then use DynamoDB's Mapper API to load and save those objects.

The problem is that the API requires the annotation `@DynamoDBTable` on my POJO. This is a compile-time annotation requires a table name parameter and so would preclude me using the POJO in a dynamic manner. [DynamoDBMapperConfig](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.html) seems intended to allow just such dynamic behavior changes. Unfortunately, it is not working for me: I get a client-side DDB error saying that my POJO fails validation because of the empty string I put in the annotation.

I have looked repeatedly for why my DynamoDBMapperConfig is not being respected but can't find anything. My code is below, stripped down to the essentials:

My POJO:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "") // table name must be overridden on each call
public class TableEntry {
    . . .
}
```

My client:

```
public class MyMapper {
    private final DynamoDBMapper mapper;
    private final DynamoDBMapperConfig configs;

    public MyMapper(String tableName) {
        AmazonDynamoDBClient client = . . .;
        mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
        configs = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder()
            .withTableNameOverride(TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(tableName))
            .build();
    }

    . . .

    public void getEntry(String key) {
        return mapper.load(TableEntry.class, key, configs);
    }
}
```

When I run my code (substantially similar to what I have pasted here), I get the following message:

```
2 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'tableName' failed to satisfy constraint: . . .
```

It goes on to say that (1) the table name is too short and (2) the table name doesn't match their regex pattern.

Any suggestions why my dynamically-named tables won't work with the DynamoDB Mapper API? Documentation references are much appreciated.

[I have found where the DynamoDBMapper [retrieves the table name](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L590-L606) but I haven't found any clues in there yet.]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`DynamoDBMapperConfig` is not a static/global class. You need to pass it to the `DynamoDBMapper` constructor.

```
    AmazonDynamoDBClient client = . . .;
    mapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder().withTableNameOverride(TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(tableName))
        .build();
    mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client, mapperConfig);
```

Comment: You seem partially right: I should be passing my config in the constructor to make it cleaner. But the documentation of the constructor say: "config - The default configuration to use for all service calls. It can be overridden on a per-operation basis." I override it when I make the actual get request: return mapper.load(TableEntry.class, key, configs);

Comment: or better yet, use `withTableNameResolver` instead of override and "functional" your way into determining the correct table name to use each time.